# CSS not rendering in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working through Chapter 5 of Michael Hartl's tutorial.

So the home page of my app currently looks like this

(https://softcover.s3.amazonaws.com/636/ruby_on_rails_tutorial/images/figures/layout_no_logo_or_custom_css_bootstrap_rails_4.png)

But it should look like this

(https://softcover.s3.amazonaws.com/636/ruby_on_rails_tutorial/images/figures/sample_app_only_bootstrap_4_0.png)

I updated my config/app file and added a custom css.scss file, but the CSS is not rendering as expected.

Here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.
  # gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  # gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  # gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  # gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.4.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

config/application.rb file ... I added config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif), this may have caused the problem

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
  end
end
```

app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: Why are you adding this to the precompilation, it's already included by default. And how and where are you including this custom.css.scss file? That is probably the one that is missing from precompilation.

Comment: If I'm reading the tutorial correctly, the custom.css.scss file should be automatically included as a part of application.css file that is included in the site layout.  so do you suggest that I remove the line "config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)"?

Comment: You don't need to add custom.css.scss to precompilation if it isn't being used as a standalone file. Yeah, this line is not needed.

Comment: Are you running in production or development mode by the way?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check that?  I'm pretty new to rails.

Comment: So should I delete custom.css.scss completely?

Comment: Well, I don't know how the tutorial is done, I'm just saying you don't need to add it to the compilation if you include it in application.css

Comment: How are you starting the server, it's most likely development if you're not sure.

Comment: I use rails server to start the server

Comment: @user3808138, Can you check in the browser (Chrome DevTools or similar) if Bootstrap is being referenced? Probably means there will be a bootstrap.css file in the Resources?

Comment: @1andsock In chrome, I right clicked the page and chose 'inspect element'.  Under sources - stylesheets there is a application.css file, but that file is empty.  There does not seem to be a bootstrap.css file in Resources

Comment: Just one more thing, the custom.css.scss file is saved as a scss file, not sure if this is a cause for the problem or not

Comment: @user3808138, are you referencing custom.css.scss in application.css?

Comment: @user3808138, Make sure application.css has `*= require_tree .` inside it, or includes custom.css.scss directly

Comment: ok this might be the problem, there is no application.css file, where is the file normally located?  which folder?  should I create one? I searched for application.css in my app directory, and couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is you aren't referencing the custom.css.scss in your application.css file. Make sure your application.css file looks like:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

Another idea is to instead rename application.css to application.**scss** and then I'd do something like:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom";
```

and then you could take out the `@import "bootstrap"` from the custom.css.scss

Comment: Thank you!  I used your suggestion for the application.css file (which I had to create myself, it was missing).  Do you generally have to create your own application.css file?

Comment: Another question, which file/code is responsible for the change from the first webpage and the one?  Is it the custom.css.scss file?

Comment: @user3808138, application.css is created by default when you create a rails app, so I'm not sure why yours was missing.

Comment: @user3808138, Rails by default combines all the styles defined in application.css each time you visit a webpage. Before, you didn't have custom.css.scss referenced, so you were loading no styles. With the new code, your loading bootstrap's styles, and all the styles you defined in custom.css.scss.